# Proof that the sequence $(u_n)$ doesn't have a limit $L$.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

So, in my real analysis I course we've seen that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n$ doesn't exist, but we haven't formally proved why it doesn't exist. I tried coming up with a proof but it feels a bit weird. Note: I didn't want to use the theorems about subsequences, I would prefer to find a proof with epsilon/delta definition because I'm trying to learn this technique, but I couldn't find one.

So what I did:
Suppose the limit exists, let's call it $L$ and $L \in \mathbb{R}.$
Then $L$ should be equal to 1 and -1 since these are the only elements in the sequence. But this is a contradiction because if a limit exists, there is only a unique limit. So the limit of this sequence doesn't exist. \QED

Comment: How do you prove that $L$ should be equal to $1$ and $-1$ without using theorems about subsequences?

Comment: So, if $u_1=1$ and $u_n=-1$ if $n>1$, then, in your opinion, the sequence $u_1,u_2,u_3,\ldots$ also doesn't have a limit, by the same argument. Am I right?

Comment: If a sequence assumes only finitely many values, then it's true that if it converges then it must converge to one of those values. So (if it exists) $L$ should be equal to $-1$ **OR** $1$. You are saying that $L$ should be equal to $-1$ **AND** $1$ without any justification.

Comment: Okay it's becoming clear now that my proof isn't correct. How can I prove this with the epsilon delta technique? I don't know how to start since my sequence always jumps from one value to the other.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I reasoned incorrectly.

Comment: @AnotherUser Thank you for the question, I made me see that I'm wrong because the sequence you mention has a limit and it's -1. Do you know how to proof my statement with epsilon/delta technique?

Comment: Write down the definition of a limit existing. Can you contradict that definition in this case?

Comment: Just consider when $L\in \{\pm 1\}$ and when  $L\notin \{\pm 1\}$

Comment: The contradiction of the limit definition is: $\exists \delta > 0: \forall N \in \mathbb{N} : n > N$ and $\mid u_{n}-l \mid> \delta$. @Paul I'll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof fails because you don't justify why the limit has to be both $1$ and $-1$.

You wish to prove that, for every $L\in\Bbb R$, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for every $N\in\Bbb N$, you have $\bigl|L-(-1)^n\bigr|\geqslant\varepsilon$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n\geqslant N$. So, take some real number $L$. Since $L$ can't be both $1$ and $-1$ at once, you can take $\varepsilon=|1-L|$ if $L\ne1$ and take $\varepsilon=|-1-L|(=|1+L|)$ if $L\ne-1$. If $L\ne1$ and if $N$ is any natural number, then $N$ is either odd or even. If $N$ is odd, let $n=N+1$; otherwise, let $n=N$. In both cases, $n\geqslant N$ and $n$ is even. And you have $|L-(-1)^n|=|L-1|=\varepsilon\geqslant\varepsilon$.

The case in which $L\ne-1$ is similar.

Comment: Thank you for this proof. I've read it multiple times and I think I understand now. :)